# How to add the column content in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, count

So i have a mysql table which stores the sizes. And i am trying to echo all the sizes as one. So if i have 3 results, i want the sizes added together. At the moment its just echoing the results.

So if i have 3 results in my table, 1=10, 2=30 and 3=50, i want it to echo 90. So how can i do this. At the moment its just echoing each one.

```
<?php

$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `files`");

$query->execute();

$row = $query->fetchAll();

return $row['size'];

?>
```

Comment: look into the SUM() function

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sum-function.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the `SUM` in the query. In other words:

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT SUM(size) sumSize FROM `files`");
....
return $row['sumSize'];
```